# Controlling frame rate of swf file

Tags: html, frame-rate

I want a swf file in my webpage. That file shows the frame rate of the document . Here is how i put it in my webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"
        width="550" height="400" id="gamefile">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <embed src="fps.swf"
           quality="high"
           width="550"
           height="400"
           play="true"
           loop="true"
           allowScriptAccess="always"
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
           pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

The file is working properly, but it shows the frame rate as around 60. The file I made in flash had a frame rate of 120 and I want the frame rate to be 120 only while showing in webpage, but it is currently showing 60

Can somebody out there help me?? You help is much appreciated...